# How do i forward input value to freeradius?

Tags: authorization, freeradius, radius

I have a form page which has username login option and i want to add email login option as well. I use freeradius server for authorization.
Login with username works fine username field goes as parameter to radius server. I can reach it by {'User-Name'}

Here is the problem:
The second option that i add email field doesn't hit to server as request. I have read the documentation. Before fowarding packet to radius server NAS looks for what Radius server understands.
So i need set something like :

```
{Email} = my-form-email
```

but where do I do that?
I tried adding line to radutmp file however it didn't work

my form looks like this

```
<input name="my-form-email" value="example@example.com">
<input name="password">
```

Any ideas?